# Long execution of SQL query in Spark due to broadcasting

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

Currently I use Spark SQL to execute large query, which selects data from external table in Hive. The query forms 64 tables through WITH statement and contains 65 LEFT JOINs of small table with big tables; small table contains from 100 to 200 thousand records i.e. about 150 thousand records and big tables contain about 5-10 million records in average.

Initially the execution time varied from 50 minutes to 80 minutes with `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=1`; after I left this option by default as mazaneicha suggested, the execution time increased up to 130 minutes. Most of this execution time (about 40-80 minutes) falls on broadcasting, when the query is not actually executed, but is being prepared for execution. Please see the example of Spark SQL output below:

```
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  FileInputFormat:247 - Total input paths to process : 1
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  FileInputFormat:247 - Total input paths to process : 1
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  FileInputFormat:247 - Total input paths to process : 1
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  FileInputFormat:247 - Total input paths to process : 1
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  FileInputFormat:247 - Total input paths to process : 1
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  CodeGenerator:54 - Code generated in 14.347002 ms
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  CodeGenerator:54 - Code generated in 26.140162 ms
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  CodeGenerator:54 - Code generated in 35.269363 ms
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  CodeGenerator:54 - Code generated in 27.790616 ms
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_80 stored as values in memory (estimated size 298.2 KB, free 4.1 GB)
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_80_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 27.9 KB, free 4.1 GB)
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  BlockManagerInfo:54 - Added broadcast_80_piece0 in memory on <HOST>:35221 (size: 27.9 KB, free: 4.1 GB)
2020-02-21 11:19:56 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Created broadcast 80 from
```

Similar output I see very long time before the actual execution of query.
Such long time upsets me and I'm trying to find ways to reduce execution time as I need to execute this query for each day in 2019 and 2020 years. 
For example, I added broadcast hint, hoping that it will speed up broadcasting ([sql performance tuning in spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html)). I also added coalesce and repartition hints as follows:

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <table_name>
PARTITION (date='2020-02-20')
SELECT 
/*+ BROADCAST(base_features) */
/*+ COALESCE(8192) */
/*+ REPARTITION(8192) */
COALESCE(...
```

I run the query as follows:

```sh
--master yarn --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 32G --executor-cores 8 --driver-memory 8G --conf "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=500000" --conf "spark.network.timeout=510000" -f query.hql
```

and currently it takes about 60-70 minutes to complete.

I added increased timeouts in order to avoid killed tasks and exceptions in the end of the execution.

I am also tried `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` statement, but the output is large and poorly interpreted and contains sensitive information, which I cannot share. What I can pay attention in the file?

Is the problem in query? Maybe it is useful to use `CACHE TABLE` statement for small table, but I do not know how to do it correctly.

Comment: 1) That log fragment doesn't seem to show anything, in fact it shows that one of the broadcast tables is created in less than a second. I think `explain()` output will be more useful; 2) You should NOT set `broadcastTimeout` to 1 second if you want to use broadcast joins; 3) Maybe try to increase the number of partitions for your large table in order to increase parallelism (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24940).

Comment: mazaneicha, thank you for your comment. I fixed the initial message according to your suggestions.